# number of ways to seat 6 students (3 females and 3 males)

Tags: probability, statistics

we have 3 female and 3 male students traveling to spain. On the plane we have 3 seats on each side of the gangway, kinda like this: |A B C | |D E F|

a) Suppose At this point that one female sits to the left and one male to the right side of the gangway Find the number of ways the students can sit down

I know the number of ways everyone could have sit down is 6!=720? not sure how to deal with the one female to the left and one male to the right part.. or 6c4 to find out all the ways the other 4 can get seated or something?

b) Suppose now that all the students freely draw cards for the seats A, B, C, D, E, F, what is the probability that the oldest male and the youngest female both get to sit at the gangway? and what is the probability that exactly one of them gets gangway seat?

I dont really know how to go about this one either except I'll probably have to divide by 720? or am I way off?

any tips/solutions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I know the number of ways everyone could have sit down is 6!=720? not sure how to deal with the one female to the left and one male to the right part.. or 6c4 to find out all the ways the other 4 can get seated or something?

Almost.  Count the ways to choose one of the females and one of the males for the specified seats (where there's only one way to arrange them), then count the ways to arrange the rest in the remaining seats.

$${^3C_1}\times {^3C_1}\times 1\times 4!$$

Note: It's *not* $^6C_2$ because you need to select one male and one female, not any two of the six students.

> > Suppose now that all the students freely draw cards for the seats A, B, C, D, E, F, what is the probability that the oldest male and the youngest female both get to sit at the gangway?
>
> I dont really know how to go about this one either except I'll probably have to divide by 720? or am I way off?

You're on.  The favoured case is counted by counting the ways to arrange the specified students in the specified seats, then counting the arrangements of the rest of the students in the remaining seats.  This is then divide by the count of all possible arrangements, to give the probability.

In this case there's just one way to select the specified students, but they can sit in either of the specified seats.

> > and what is the probability that exactly one of them gets gangway seat?

In this case we have two favoured cases, each where *one of the two* specified students and one of the four *not-specified* students are arranged in the specified seats and the rest arranged in the remaining seats.

Can you do this now?

Comment: hmm not really, I dont get where the 1 is from on the first question? and I dont understand that much either on b) "then counting the arrangements of the rest of the students in the remaining seats." thats just 4! right? (same as on a?)

Comment: @abpoir123 The 1 is simply because there is one way to arrange the two specified students (male on the right, female on the left).  Where as in (b) there are $2!$ ways to arrange the specified students after you select them.  And yes, the ways to select the rest is $4!$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp The question asks for 1 female to the left of the gangway (i.e. in 1 of 3 seats) and 1 male to the right. All this does is eliminate the 1 option of all males to the left and all females to the right so $6!-1=719$

Comment: naah, a) should be correct I think, if that is what you are wondering @dale M 1 female on the left of the gangway (in 1 of 3 seats) and 1 male on the right side of the gangway (in 1 of 3 seats) ?

Comment: but would b1 be 3c1*3c1*2!*4! or maybe 2!*4! ?

Comment: or is that wrong? and what about part 2 on b?

Comment: @DaleM Ah! That depends on if you read it as "immediately to the left" or "anywhere to the left".  I interpreted it as "immediately".

Comment: @abpoir123 There's only one way to choose the youngest female and eldest male. They are specific individuals.  Then there are $2!$ ways to arrange them, and $4!$ ways to arrange the remainder.

Comment: @abpoir123 For the other half; choose one of the two specified individual, choose someone other than the other one, arrange them in the 2 specified places, then arrange the remainder.

Comment: well the one specified individual can be placed in 2ways?.. naah I dont really understand this one??

Comment: plss.. can you help me out with this last one aswell?? I still cant figure it out :)